# omniorb makefile server error

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile

Im doing some adition simple program on omniorb 4.2 but the makefile for server gives me an error.
Heres my makeserver file code:

```
CC            = gcc
CPPFLAGS      = -g -c
LDFLAGS       = -g
OMNI_HOME     = /opt/omniorb
OMNI_INCLUDES = -I$(OMNI_HOME)/include
OMNI_LIB_DIR  = $(OMNI_HOME)/lib
OMNIIDL       = $(OMNI_HOME)/bin/omniidl
INCLUDES      = $(OMNI_INCLUDES)
LIBS          = -lomniORB4 -lomnithread -lomniDynamic4
OBJECTS       = Data.o CServiceA.o Server.o

all Server: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o Server -L$(OMNI_HOME)/lib $(OBJECTS)         $(LIBPATH) $(LIBS)

Data.o: DataSK.cc Data.hh
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) DataSK.cc

Server.o: Server.cpp Data.hh
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) Server.cpp

CServiceA.o: CServiceA.cpp CServiceA.h Data.hh
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) CServiceA.cpp

DataSK.cc: Data.idl
    $(OMNI_HOME)/bin/omniidl -bcxx Data.idl

clean clean_all:
    rm -fr *.o
    rm -fr core
    rm -fr *.hh
    rm -fr *SK.cc
    rm -fr Server
```

And this is the error it gives me:

```
$ make -f MakeServer 
gcc -g -c -I/opt/omniorb/include DataSK.cc
gcc -g -c -I/opt/omniorb/include CServiceA.cpp
gcc -g -c -I/opt/omniorb/include Server.cpp
gcc -g -o Server -L/opt/omniorb/lib Data.o CServiceA.o Server.o  -        lomniORB4 -lomnithread -lomniDynamic4
gcc: error: Data.o: file or directory doesn't exist
MakeServer:13: fail in instructions for objective 'all'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following rule is broken

```
Data.o: DataSK.cc Data.hh
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) DataSK.cc
```

You've told make that this rule creates `Data.o`, but it actually creates `DataSK.o`, so change the rule and `OBJECTS`

```
OBJECTS       = DataSK.o CServiceA.o Server.o

DataSK.o: DataSK.cc DataSK.hh
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) DataSK.cc
```

---

As as side note, a lot of your makefile is unnecessary, the built-in rules and gcc dependency generation can cover most of the work:

```
omni_home := /opt/omniorb

CPPFLAGS := -I$(omni_home)/include -MMD -MP
CXXFLAGS := -g
LDFLAGS  := -L$(omni_home)/lib
LDLIBS   := -lomniORB4 -lomnithread -lomniDynamic4

objs := DataSK.o CServiceA.o Server.o
deps := $(objs:.o=.d)

.PHONY: all clean

all: Server

Server: CC := g++
Server: $(objs)

DataSK.o: DataSK.cc
DataSK.cc DataSK.hh: Data.idl
    $(omni_home)/bin/omniidl -bcxx $<

clean: ; $(RM) $(objs) $(deps) DataSK.cc DataSK.hh Server

-include $(deps)
```

(The above may not work correctly as I haven't tested it.)

Comment: Well, that was the problem after all. Now i have another problem running the server. I start omniNames, but trying to run the server gives me a `corba::system exception`
I forgot, your code was better than mine, i used too for client. Without 2 dots works great. I have a question, for what purpose are .d files?
This is the error ./Server gives me:
    `$ ./Server
    'IOR:010000001600000049444c3a446174612f53657276696365413a312    e30000000010000000000000064000000010102000c0000003139322e3    136382e312e3500b9e3000...'
    Caught CORBA::SystemException.`

Comment: I can't help you with the exception with that amount of information, try starting a new question as it's unrelated to this one. The `.d` files are makefile fragments generated by GCC that store the dependencies so you don't have to write things like  `CServiceA.o: DataSK.hh`, try reading one if you're curious.

Comment: Oh... ok. I will try it, thx for helping me out. Well, problem solved.